# Cross-Origin error with Authorization in AngularJs

Tags: c#, angularjs, authorization, cross-domain

I am trying to setup a Authorized call from my WebAPI.

The method looks like:

```
    [Authorize]
    [DynamicAuthorizeGroupRoles(DRoles = "Failures")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Authorization/Test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
    {
        Logger.Write(this.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        return "Access granted".ToJSONResponse();
    }
```

If I call it directly from the browser it works fine. However when I do that from my AngularJS page I get the following error:

***Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://.../Authorization/Test. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*').***

This is how my config looks like:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }
```

Globals.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnableCrossDomainCall();                
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enable cross domain call
        ///     To Use post requests between domain
        /// </summary>
        private void EnableCrossDomainCall()
        {


            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {

                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            }

        }
```

I tried several attemps without success. Any idea why this is happening or what I need to change?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Sorry, but this does not really help me. I know the basics, however with the above configuration all other webapi calls are working. I only have trouble with the posted Authorization one. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It not your WebApi Project that is have CORS issues. Put a crossdomain file in the web root of site hosting the Angular.  If you use IIS to serve the website then add  `<location path="crossdomain.xml">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clear />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/x-cross-domain-policy" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>`
to the webconfig of the host website